# Pb connection from client to postgresql server

Tags: postgresql

I've no problem to access to postgresql server from local machine with two methods (localhost or specific ip ).
But when i try to connect from client machine to the postgresql server (in other pc using network lan), i have this error : **can't connect to the server**.
These steps were verified in computer which include postgresql server:

- listen_adresses='*'  ==> OK in postgresql.conf file
- host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 => Ok in  pg_hba.conf file
  _ postgresql rule is inserted in inbound windows firewall including these parameters : protocol type : TCP, local port: specific ports: 5432, action: allow connection, profiles: domain, private and public all checked
  I've verified with ping  all it's ok
  but when I try to connect from client machine to postgresql server the problem persist.
  Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: i am missing outgoing traffic, only letting the inboud traffic doesn_'t seem enoughm, you can run wireshark and see how the traffic fows, also you can enable the firewall log for all traffic, but only temporary it increases wuickly

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

I've added ODBC to the client machine with IP server + allowing port 5432 and every thing ran fine.